# Binding non-boolean values to CheckBox in Table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am having trouble to bind a String value of `00` and `98` to `false` and `true`. I have found quite a few possible solutions but none of them works for me and I don't quite understand why.

Suppose I receive data from a server and create a JSON Model and set that to the table model.

```
function createTableColumns(columns) {
        var oTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("mainTable");

        var statusTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
            editable: false,
            // THIS WAS MY FIRST ATTEMPT TO GET IT WORKING
            //checked: {
            //    path: "{TableModel>status}",
            //    formatter: function(val) {
            //        console.log(val);
            //        return val === "98";
            //    }
            //}
        });

        // SECOND ATTEMPTS, DOESN'T WORK EITHER
        statusTemplate.bindProperty("checked", "{TableModel>status}", function(val) { return val === "98"; });

        for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
             oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                 label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: columns[i]}),
                 name: columns[i],
                 flexible: false,
                 autoResizable: true,
                 template: columns[i] === 'status' ? statusTemplate : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{TableModel>" + columns[i] + "}"}),
                 sortProperty: columns[i],
                 filterProperty: columns[i],
             }));
        }
    }
```

Both ways in the code above do not work. I don't know whether it is the logic or whether I am using the model wrong. Every other (TextView) Column displays data to which it is bound... so I believe that the binding is correct!?

I also have tried this way but that doesn't work at all for me: [OpenUI5 binding property with a function, instead of direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323120/openui5-binding-property-with-a-function-instead-of-direct-access)
I keep on getting the error that "00" is not a valid value for the checkbox.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

**EDIT: Current state**

This function is basically called everytime the user switches
the table in the application. The old data (rows and columns) will be 
deleted and filled new. The parameter columns contains an array of 
strings of the column names! No data is in the data model yet!!!

```
function createTableColumns(columns) {
    var oTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("mainTable");

    oTable.destroyColumns();
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(null, "TableModel");

    var statusCheckBoxTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
        text: "{TableModel>status}",
        editable: false,
        checked: {
            path: "{TableModel>status}",
            formatter: function(v) {
                console.debug(v);
                if(v === "98") return true;
                else return false;
            }
        }
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if(columns[i] !== 'rowid') {
            oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: columns[i]}),
                name: columns[i],
                flexible: false,
                autoResizable: true,
                template: columns[i] === 'status' ? statusCheckBoxTemplate : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{TableModel>" + columns[i] + "}"}),
                sortProperty: columns[i],
                filterProperty: columns[i],
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

After a user selected a table to display it sits there only displaying
the columns. Data is fetched from the server (ajax call) as an JSON object and a data model is created. It all works fine. Data is bound without problems and displayed correctly.

```
function tableBtnReloadPressed() {
    // ajax call
    var tabledata = readTableData(ACTIVE_TABLE);
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(tabledata);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "TableModel");
    var oTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("mainTable");
    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindRows("TableModel>/");
}
```

**EDIT: Third try with factory**

```
function createTableColumns(columns) {
    var oTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("mainTable");

    oTable.destroyColumns();
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(null, "TableModel");

    sap.ui.model.SimpleType.extend("BooleanStringType", {
        formatValue: function(s) {
            console.debug(typeof s, s);
            return s === "98";
        },
        parseValue: function(s) {
            console.debug(typeof s, s)
            return s ? "98" : "00";
        },
        validateValue: function(s) {
            console.debug(typeof s, s)
        }
    });

    var statusCheckBoxTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
        text: "{TableModel>status}",
        editable: false,
        //checked: {
        //    path: "{TableModel>status}",
        //    formatter: function(v) {
        //        console.debug(v);
        //        if(v === "98") return true;
        //        else return false;
        //    }
        //}
    });

    statusCheckBoxTemplate.bindProperty("checked", {
        path: "{TableModel>status}",
        type: new BooleanStringType()
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if(columns[i] !== 'rowid') {
            oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: columns[i]}),
                name: columns[i],
                flexible: false,
                autoResizable: true,
                template: columns[i] === 'status' ? statusCheckBoxTemplate : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{TableModel>" + columns[i] + "}"}),
                sortProperty: columns[i],
                filterProperty: columns[i],
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simplify to get it working. First thing is to use a textview / label to check if the binding is working. Only then change to the checkbox and use a formatter / custom datatype for the conversion.
For instance, this is not valid (from the code above):

```
checked: {
  path: "{TableModel>status}",
```

because when you pass an explicit path property, you should not use the `{}` in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I put this into jsbin and played arount wiht it a bit. [jsbin with solution](http://jsbin.com/pocojozimi/edit?html,console,output)

The correct template for the checkbox is this:

```
var statusCheckBoxTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
        text: "{TableModel>status}",
        editable: false,
        checked: {
            path: "TableModel>status",
            formatter: function(v) {
                return(v === "98");
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit: @jumpifzero beat me to it. But I wanted to edit my post for a complete picture. Such an easy to miss answer. ^^"

Comment: I have changed my code (for the first solution in the `formatter`) but it still does not work. The other thing that is strange is that the `console.log` command is never called. I never see an output with Firebug. So it maybe never is called. __EDIT:__ it does get called if I change my path to `TableModel/status` (changeing the `>` to a `/`. It still doesn't work but atleast I see an output now. But this path to the data in the model is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: The `/` is fine for the path. Did you check the type of the status from the model? Did you check the result of the comparison? Did you try using `==`? I think from here on it is pure JS debugging to see what is happening and returned by the formatter function.

Comment: the types of all data in the model are string, I checked that. I also tryed `==` but got the same result. I can't check the result of the comparisson because the function is never called. I placed a `console.debug` inside it but I never get an output.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code parts from the current state?

Comment: I have already tryed this but only got errors. I will retry it and report back. Maybe I did something wrong the last time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86681/discussion-between-carsten-and-ap0).